# need to implement Undo function using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

need to implement undo function in a state array data. i remove the data by id using filter method but i need to restore the data after click on undo button. how to implement in React Hooks?

```
const [dataSource, setDatasource] = useState([
{
    id:   1,
    name: 'john',
    gender: 'm'
  },
  {
    id:   2,
    name: 'mary',
    gender: 'f'
  },
{
    id:   3,
    name: 'loki',
    gender: 'M'
  },
{
    id:   4,
    name: 'Thor',
    gender: 'M'
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep track of all the actions that the user performs, and calculate the end result from that. When a user clicks "undo", you can just remove the latest action.

```js
const actions = [
  {
    operation: "create",
    name: "Some name",
    index: 1
  },
  {
    operation: "delete",
    index: 1
  }
];

const state = (() => {
  let appliedState = [];

  for (const action of actions) {
    if (action.operation === "create") {
      appliedState .push(action.name);
    } else if (action.operation === "delete") {
      appliedState = appliedState .filter(currentState => currentState.index !== action.index);
    }
  }
  return appliedState ;
})();
```

[You can see a working react example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-voice-0o8ego?file=/src/App.js)